# System beeps continuously if both RAM sticks inserted

Tags: memory, computer-building

I have two sticks of OCZ 2GB PC2 9600 RAM. When I attempt to boot with both sticks inserted, I am met with a continuous string of system beeps (and no bootup). The system boots fine when only one stick is inserted, but obviously that leaves me with less RAM than I'd like to have. What could the problem be?

System specs are:

- Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3L
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400
- Sticks of OCZ 2GB PC2 9600 RAM
- Zotac GeForce GTS 250 1GB
- 2x Seagate 500GB SATA HDs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very important that you check your motherboard manual before purchasing RAM. Most manuals have a section that shows an approved RAM list. I have found that I got stuck on several occasions because I forgot to check this. You may also have different slots on your mother board and only certain types / combinations of RAM will work. when in doubt, check your MB manual!!

Danbo

Comment: +1 http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Memory/motherboard_memory_ga-ep45-ud3l.pdf  I don't see OCZ PC2-9600 on the list, faster and slower variants but not 9600.

Comment: Ok, I'm totally feeling like an idiot now for having a coworker build me a system under the idea of "I've been out of the game too long." Crazy that he didn't check the speeds! At least this is a cheap part to replace now. Odd that it works with one stick though...

Answer (score 4):

A photo of the motherboard in question shows 4 slots, 2 colors, 2 groups, one of each color per group. Did you put both sticks in a single group, or did you put them in slots of the same color?

AFAIK, the colors designate a bank of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Either one of your memory sticks or one of your memory slots is damaged.

You will need to run a series of tests.

1. Take stick A and insert into slot 1. Boot the machine. Does it work? If so then that combination is good.
2. Take stick A and insert into slot 2. Boot the machine. Does it work? If so then both slots are good as is stick A.
3. Take stick B and insert into slot 1. Boot the machine. Does it work?
4. Take stick B and insert into slot 2. Boot the machine. Does it work?

If it was the memory at fault I would have expected test 1 or 3 to fail showing that one of the memory sticks is broken.

Slightly less likely is that test 2 (or 4) fails showing that one of your memory slots is broken.

The last possibility it that all 4 tests pass and it's the combination that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is like my motherboard (a Gigabyte too), has 4 slots (2 blue, 2 white), but the 4 slots can be used only with single-sided RAM. With double-sided ram, only the two blue slots will be used.

Comment: The user manual of your mobo does not mention this limitation, while mine does. Probably is not that.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the blue slot; it only supports 4GB and the sticks need to be identical.

The white slot on the other hand supports a single stick of 8GB.